# Typescript: inferable optional tuple type

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I am trying to create a generic type that would be a tuple of 2 types, both of which are optional, otherwise defaulting to void.

```
/** Initial attempt */
type IO<I = void, O = void> = [I, O];
/** resolves as `false` */
type Test = [string, number] extends IO ? true : false;
```

In this instance typescript complained that it only expects both of the types to be void, rather than defaulting to them.

```
/** Second attempt replacing `void` with `any` */
type IO<I = any, O = any> = [I?, O?];
type Test = [string, number] extends IO ? true : false;
```

Replacing `void` with `any` worked, but it broke the ability to infer omitted types as `void`;

```
type InferI<Test extends IO<any, any>> = Test extends IO<infer I, any> ? I : never;
type InferO<Test extends IO<any, any>> = Test extends IO<any, infer O> ? O : never;
/** resolves as `unknown` instead of `void` */
type O = InferO<[string, number]>;
```

I have tried a couple of other options, but it always came down to infering an omitted ttype as `unknown`, and I could quite grasp why setting `void` as the defaults for the generic types makes Typescript always expect void;

EDIT:
Turns out I overcomplicated things and could have kept my initial attempt, which was blocked by attempting to create the following config

```
interface IOConfig {
  [key: string]: IO;
}
interface Test extends IOConfig {
  test: [string, number];
}
```

But I could have just specified `IO<any, any>` to prevent the confusion.
Thanks to @Cuzy for making me take another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type Test = [string, number] extends IO ? true : false;`

should be

`type Test = [string, number] extends IO<string, number> ? true : false;`

Since you've defaulted both type parameters to `void` the resulting type of `IO` will always be `[void, void]` unless the type parameters are specified otherwise.

Comment: I though of that, but the next step would be defining a Record where the values are Tuples of any configuration, I had though this approach would break that, but I may have been mistaken, I'll need to try again.

Comment: @seMikel If you want you can give me an example so I can take a look at it!